# Why SATA ALIGN primitive is shifted or swapped on 7-Series GTXE2 transceiver RXDATA output?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, sata, virtex-series-fpga

I am using a Xilinx 7-Series GTXE2 Transceiver configured as SATA host PHY. This transceiver is interfacing with an SATA Host controller and an SATA Gen1 device.

During initialization, I am able to see COMRESET, COMINIT and COMWAKE from host and device. They have been captured on RXDATA/TXDATA. TX/RXELECIDLE are de-asserted correctly. The host controller is able to receive and response to complete OOB sequence.

After that, the host is sending `D10.2` at 1.5 Gbps to start speed negotiation.  The device is responding with \$ALIGN_p\$ primitives, which are send at 1.5 Gbps.

However, from RXDATA, I can only see `D27.3 D10.2 D10.2 K28.5` symbols appearing for only one clock cycle, which is 20'haaaaa, follow by 20'h5f0e4. After that, I am seeing 20'h55555, follow by 20'h5f0e4. The `D27.3` and `K28.5` character appeared to be correct. `D10.2` appeared to be either swapped or shifted. Because the GTXE2 transceiver is unable to decode \$ALIGN_p\$, the speed negotiation failed.

I have set `RXCDR_CFG` to (72'h0380008BFF40100008). The FPGA is connected to a Gen1 device.

I have implemented a control signal to release `RXCDRHOLD` when I find 20'haaaaa follow by 20'h5f0e4 in the data stream. After I release the `hold` signal, it becomes 20'h55555 and 20'h5f0e4. If I don't release `RXCDRHOLD`, I see garbage on `RXDATA`. So it seems that releasing `RXCDRHOLD` only improve part of the \$ALIGN_p\$ characters. `K28.5` and `D27.3` was right. `D10.2` is bit swapped or shifted.

I have came across another post, wherein the author may have experienced similar problems. He modified `RXCDR_CFG`: [Configuring a 7-Series GTXE2 transceiver for Serial-ATA (Gen1/2/3)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125243/configuring-a-7-series-gtxe2-transceiver-for-serial-ata-gen1-2-3)

I was wondering, if anyone has experienced this problem with Xilinx 7-Series GTXE2 transceivers.

Comment: Could you please post a waveform containing `RDXDATA`, `RXELECIDLE`, `RXCDRHOLD`, and `RXCOMWAKEDET`.

Comment: What is the device? (HDD, SSD, vendor, fabrication year). Did you use the Xilinx Core Generator or Vivado equivalent to generate the GTXE2 instance? => the generated code has bugs and is partly not correct for the SATA protocol. What's your test board? How do you connect your FPGA to a SATA cable: SFP adapter, SMA adapter, ...?

Comment: When exactly do you release `RXCDRHOLD`? You must wait until the complete OOB handshake phase is over, because the OOB bursts are filled with \$ALIGN_p\$ symbols. I'm also waiting for at least 63 consecutive detected ALIGN symbols. So the ALIGN stream from device is stable.

Comment: we tried another SATA drive: 
Western Digital WD Green WD10EADS

I am seeing the output of rxdata_out of instant gtwizard_0_GT are inverted.
gtwizard_0_GT is the wrapper of GTXE2_CHANNEL, generated by vivado. 
I expected when GTX sending ALIGN primitive, it appear as burst of :
0011100100 | 1010101010 | 1010101010 | 0101111100
D27.3                D10.2               D10.2                 K28.5

From chipscope, I see bit is inverted:
1100011011 | 0101010101 | 0101010101 | 1010000011

Comment: I applied a little hack @ rxdata . 
assign rx_data_out_new = ~rxdata_out.

I wonder if you have seen this before? it seems to me that I would get different result from different SATA drive.

Comment: I finally can link up the drive by using the hack.

Answer (score 2):

I thought again about your inversion problem. The problem is that you or your PCB or your device swapped the RX+ and RX- wires for the transceiver input.

Your GTXE2 is configured to a 20-bit bus and no 8B/10B encoding, so the direct inversion of each bit seen in your measurement is caused by the wrong polarity at the input pins. You can enable polarity inversion (`RXPOLARITY`) for RX in the transceiver. The option is used to swap the pins, because PCB designers might swap the wires to reduce hops and vias.

You should also look into your boards schematic if there is a hint for swapped wires.

Comment: I modified the xdc file for RXN/P by changing from 
set_property PACKAGE_PIN AN3 [get_ports MOCARXN]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN AN4 [get_ports MOCARXP]
To:
set_property PACKAGE_PIN AN3 [get_ports MOCARXP]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN AN4 [get_ports MOCARXN]

The link up is failed. According to chipscope, I am seeing RXDATA as 20'hA0F1B follow by 20'h55555.
It is the same result if I don't change the RXP/N location.

Comment: You can't change the pins via XDC. The XDC setting is needed by the mapping step to find the correct location, nothing more. Transceiver pins are fixed and thus can not be swapped by XDC. You need to 1) confirm if the PCB designer swapped the P and N wires and if so 2) you need to change/enable `RXPOLARITY`. It's a transceiver generic.

Comment: @sunni Did you look for the `RXPOLARITY` parameter and you schematic? Am, I guessing right?